# reading pixel value in binary using python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

how to read pixel value in binary image?

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('sc.jpg')
px = sc[1, 1]
print px
```

but the results I get are 3 red channels green and blue

```
[255 255 255]
```

based on the reference I have the pixel value on the binary image is 1 and 0
sp i am confused with this condition
thankyou :)

Comment: Did you mean to write `px = sc[1,1]`, shouldn't that be `px = img[1,1]`?

Comment: What did you expect to get? What do you mean by *"based on the reference I have the pixel value on the binary image is 1 and 0"*? Is your image black-and-white? `[255 255 255]` is white in RGB (1?) and `[0, 0, 0]` is black (0?)..

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has a mistake. The image object is named `img` not `sc`.

Second, you are seeing RGB values which go up to 255 for each channel. (255, 255, 255) is white. Presumably you are expecting black=0 and white=1 for a binary image?

You can change the imread mode to e.g. grayscale.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('sc.jpg', 0)
px = img[1, 1]
print px
```

There is no mode for binary, however, you shouldn't need this. If your image is truly saved in a binary format, opencsv should recognize this and give you a pixel value of either 1 or 0. Please check your image file is saved in the correct format!